# Pyinstaller generated exe fails to execute but the script is working once run directly

Tags: python, oracle, pyinstaller, pyodbc

I'm new to pyinstaller and  python development on Windows, so I might have missed something obvious.
My script is working fine when I run it though command line (so it cannot be the issue with Oracle client or the connection string), but fails to run the exe with the following error:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Oracle in instantclient_12_2_new, C:\\oracle\\instantclient_12_2_new\\SQORA32.dll). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
[684] Failed to execute script update_database
```

The exe was created using this command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --clean --noupx --win-private-assemblies --hidden-import='pkg_resources.py2_warn' update_database.py
```

I'm running all that on Windows 10.

Do you know what direction shall I go to debug it? Thanks!

Comment: why are you not using cx_Oracle ? it is much better than using odbc.

Comment: which version of the instant client did you install ? you need also the odbc driver for windows 10. It is 64 bits or 32 ?

Comment: it is instant client 12, my windows is 64-bit, so is Python and ODBC driver (there was some problem with 32-bit Python refusing to work with 64-bit driver)

Comment: I've never heard of cx_Oracle before, thanks, I'll check it out. ODBC is working fine though, except for Pyinstaller

Comment: if you plan to interact with Oracle, you should take a look at cx_Oracle https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/